# getValue() for SelectField

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-ui

All I simply want to do is to get the name of the **Company** and save it to the database

I was trying with do with text, and was trying to fetch using the below code

`sport: this.refs.company.getValue(),` and it was working perfect.

Then I decided to use the [SelectField from Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) for Company

And it's not fetching the data.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  value: 1,
};
}

submitResume(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.company.getValue({value}));

CreatePost.insert({
        company: this.refs.company.getValue(),

        employee: this.refs.employee.getValue(),

    });
    console.log("Employee Profile Submitted!");
}


handleNameChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

    <form onSubmit={this.submitResume.bind(this)}>

          <SelectField
                    floatingLabelText="Company Name"
                    className="validate"
                    ref="company"
                    id="company"
                    floatingLabelStyle={{fontSize:20}}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Google" />
                    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Facebook" />
                    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Amazon" />
                    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Nest" />
                    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Microsoft" />
            </SelectField>

            <TextField
                className="validate"
                type="text"
                ref="employee"
                id="employee"
                hintText="Enter Full Name"
                floatingLabelStyle={{fontSize:20}}
                floatingLabelText="Employee Name"
                multiLine={true}
                rows={1}
                fullWidth={true}
            />
```

It's working fine for TextField, but not for SelectField.

Comment: Have you tried using the `selected` property instead of `value`?

Comment: this.refs.company.selected() ? Where do I need to pass the value?

Comment: you are using the selectField as controlled component (storing the value in state variable and updating in onChange function), ref is not required here to get the value selected in selected field use: `this.state.value`.

Comment: `company: this.refs.company.getValue(),` what can I change this to?
Able to get the value in the console by `console.log(this.state.company.getValue({value}));`.
But need help in saving to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now see this updated one 
you will get your value in one of the parameter `value`, `index` or `event`

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  value: 1,
};
}

submitResume(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.company.getValue({value}));

CreatePost.insert({
        company: this.refs.company.getValue(),

        employee: this.refs.employee.getValue(),

    });
    console.log("Employee Profile Submitted!");
}


handleNameChange(event, index, value) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(value);
  this.setState({value});
}

    <form onSubmit={this.submitResume.bind(this)}>

          <SelectField
                    floatingLabelText="Company Name"
                    className="validate"
                    ref="company"
                    id="company"
                    floatingLabelStyle={{fontSize:20}}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value={"Google"} primaryText="Google" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Facebook"} primaryText="Facebook" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Amazon"} primaryText="Amazon" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Nest"} primaryText="Nest" />
                    <MenuItem value={"Microsoft"} primaryText="Microsoft" />
            </SelectField>

            <TextField
                className="validate"
                type="text"
                ref="employee"
                id="employee"
                hintText="Enter Full Name"
                floatingLabelStyle={{fontSize:20}}
                floatingLabelText="Employee Name"
                multiLine={true}
                rows={1}
                fullWidth={true}
            />
```

Comment: How can I display in console log?

Comment: still not able to get the primaryText as my output in console log.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to pass the **text value** instead of a **number**

```
<MenuItem value={"Google"}    primaryText="Google"    />
<MenuItem value={"Facebook"}  primaryText="Facebook"  />
<MenuItem value={"Amazon"}    primaryText="Amazon"    />
<MenuItem value={"Nest"}      primaryText="Nest"      />
<MenuItem value={"Microsoft"} primaryText="Microsoft" />
```